# Evaluating this limit without Taylor $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: limits

I need help with this limit, and without using Taylor series

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: Are you looking for that $\frac{x^3\sin x}{x^2+x+1}$?

Comment: If it is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3\sin x}{x^2+x+1}$, then the limit obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let consider

- for $x_n=2\pi n\to \infty \implies \frac{x_n^3\sin x_n}{x_n^2+x_n+1}\to\,?$
- for $x_n=\frac{\pi}2+2\pi n\to \infty  \implies \frac{x_n^3\sin x_n}{x_n^2+x_n+1}\to \,?$